# Самый легкий API облачных хранилищ

Tags: хранение-данных, облачное-хранилище

На курсач нужно взять реализацию клиентского приложения для работы с облачным сервисом. Кто может подсказать какой API из них можно легко использовать на PHP или С/С++ ? Чтоб можно было найти примеры, документацию и т.д. Пока больше склоняюсь к PHP и реализации оконного приложения через Devel Studio. Хочется, чтоб можно было сесть и за неделю написать перед сессией))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebDAV, как вариант. Обычный HTTP и немного дополнительных глаголов, заголовков и статусов. Простой клиент, как по мне, так делается достаточно тривиально. (Сервер сложнее из-за разнотипностей поведения зоопарка клиентов.) Собственно, чего там делать, любая адекватная библиотека для работы с HTTP это уже практически готовый WebDAV-клиент. Разве что можно какую-нибудь обертку-адаптер нарисовать, для придачи большего сходства с работой с «традиционной» файловой системой.

В облаке-шмоблаке это Яндекс.Диск и ownCloud.

Answer (score 0):

В буржуйских интернетах традиционно пилят [API Twitter'а](https://dev.twitter.com/), когда хотят показать быстрый/простой пример разработки клиента для облака.

Comment: @sergiks, понимание облака у преподавателя - Dropbox, GoogleDrive, SkyDrive, Yandex.Disk и т.д. Т.е. облачные хранилища

Comment: Тогда самое облачное облако из облаков — Amazon, и их S3, к которому есть SDK в т.ч. [для PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/)